# Align div to bottom without removing it from the flow

Tags: css, html, css-position

I need to align a div to the bottom of the parent div. You might just tell me to use `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0px;`, but I cannot remove the div from the flow.

My HTML markup looks like this:

```
<div class=parent>
    <div class=child>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>
```

The parent div has a dynamic height. Sometimes, it is just as high as necessary to show all of its content (height: auto;), but sometimes, it has a fixed height, which is smaller than the child's height. In that case, I want the child to reach outside the parent at the top edge. The child always has `height: auto;` to fit its content, which I also don't know at design-time.

[image]

What I have tried is using `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0px;` on the child div, but this removes the child from the flow; thus, the parent div will fail to show its content while it has `height: auto;` active. I also tried using `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: bottom;` on the parent, but this seems to make it impossible to give it a height smaller than the content.

If nothing helps, I can still try a JS solution, but I'm sure this has to possible using plain CSS somehow, even if I need to modify my HTML and insert a wrapper div or something.

Comment: more css please. Does one of the elements have a fixed height?

Comment: No. The parent sometimes has `height: auto;` and sometimes, as a part of an animation, a fixed height, which I don't know at design-time. The child always has `height: auto;`.

Comment: is it necessary that the second div should be a child of the first? what about putting both divs in a wrapper? second div will always be just below the first in normal flow itself :/

Comment: I don't know how that would look like to you. I'm trying to create spoilers that can be extended and collapsed by clicking on the header. Everything works so far, but I'm trying to add an animation in which the parent div changes height while the child sticks to the bottom of the parent, so it looks somewhat like the content would be pulled out of the header.

Comment: I don't get it. Just place the element as last element? Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bL8zC/1/ this is only a problem, when the parent item have fixed height, heigher than it's 100%.

Comment: The effect is supposed to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4qjBh/
The difference between the fiddle and my problem is that I need to be able to use `height: auto;` on the parent. The fiddle uses a fixed height.

Comment: You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4qjBh/1/ ?

Comment: No, because that doesn't include the animation I'm trying to accomplish. I want the animation to look exactly like in the fiddle that I posted.

Comment: @Rapti Any feedback for me?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention anymore because I built a JS workaround. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?

```
.parent {
    margin-top:-16px;
    background-color: gold;
    height: 88px;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
    transform:translateY(-100%);
    transition:1s all;
    z-index:-1;
}
.down {
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
    transform:translateY(0);
}

$(".header").click(function () {
    $(".parent").toggleClass('down');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4qjBh/5/)

You could hide the overflow above the header by using a container as well [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4qjBh/6/)

As Linek mention, browsers that don't support transforms would just show the content. In order to reach them without using a set height or taking them out of the flow, you have to over estimate the height of the element and use a negative `margin-top`. [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qjBh/7/) should fix the problem in IE8

Comment: Probably wont work on IE8 [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: @Linek The only way to not use `transform` and do the same thing (given a variable height and not take it out of the flow) is to overcompensate for the height and toggle something like `margin-top:-5000px`